# java explicitly call super method

Tags: java, inheritance

Are there any reason to call method from super class?

I have met lots of places where `super` method called instead of `this` method, e.g.:

```
public String getCustomValue() {
    String value = (String) super.getValue(someArgHere);
    return value;
}
```

Any benefits? I just see one major problem with inheritance: if I override `getValue` in this class or in one of its descendants `getCustomValue` will neglect that override and call `super` method.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, so I could just call `this.getValue(someArgHere)`

Answer (score 2):

`super.getValue(someArgHere)` calls the `getValue` method of the super class. In contrast, `this.getValue(someArgHere)` calls the `getValue` method of the current class, if defined. If the current class does not override `getValue`, the super class method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you overwrote the method `getValue(...)` and you are **really sure** (your sureness deserves a comment in the code) you want to bypass it you should not use `super` like you are doing. Later on if you or someone else decide to overwrite `getValue(...)` they probably wanted the effect to apply to `getCustomValue()` as well.

Although you definitely can call `super.myMethodOne()` from `myMethodTwo()`, the usual scenario is when you want to call `super.myMethodOne()` from `myMethodOne()` when you override it. Some languages like Ruby even pass up the method arguments automatically for you so that you don't have to retype them.

Here is one example:

```
public class A {
    public void close() {

      // do a bunch of things...
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        // close things related to the subclass B
        // and then make sure A is closed as usual...
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no technical advantages of using `super` over `this` in the case where the method is not overridden.

However, one might say that it's clearer to use `super` instead of `this` for the reason you've just mentioned.  If you override the function in your subclass, then you will need to use `super`; if you don't you *can* use `this`.  Instead of playing guessing games (or forcing people to check whether the method has been overridden), you can just *always* use `super` when you mean `super`.

Comment: +1 for guessing games. I believe an experienced person doesnt spent much time to understand logic behind but for new people it makes things complicated. I even use 'this' if my property has the same name as argument.

Answer (score 1):

> I just see one major problem with inheritance: if I override `getValue` in this class or in one of its descendants `getCustomValue` will neglect that override and call super method.

Then don't call the `super` method explicitly, just call `getValue`. If the method has not been overriden it will default to the super-method. If it has, it will use the overriden method.

I don't know if it's appropriate to ask about "benefits" in this case - it really just depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the design. When we code, we do it as per what it is!
So even if `getValue` is extended, its perfect, because that is what your class is suppose to do.

Normally, `super` is used, to obtain any information or data or side effect from the `super type` and modify or improve it as per your current class functionality

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit is if your class overrides the method of the superclass you still can call the method of the superclass using `super`.